# TypeScript source maps are not refreshed in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, typescript, source-maps

I have a large TypeScript codebase, which I compile with options like this in my `tsconfig.json` file.

```
{
  ...
  "sourceMap": true,
  "outFile": "../js/app.js",
  "target": "es5",
  ...
}
```

Often times when I recompile my TypeScript project using `tsc` in a `gulp` task, the TypeScript sources in Chrome Dev Tools get out of sync for no reason. Then later randomly it catches up and shows the correct sources. It's really annoying, as I can't debug my project, breakpoints and everything is messed up.

I tried reloading the page several times using `F5` and also using `Ctrl+F5`, but the sources are still not reloaded from the updated source map file.

I also tried to disable caching in the Dev Tools, but the issue still shows up.

I double checked that the `.map` file is indeed updated during each TypeScript compile.

I have no idea what's going on. Has anyone experienced something similar? What other could cause this, and what could be a permanent solution?

Comment: Try hitting `F12` -> Network -> Tick `Disable cache`. This helped me when I had similar issues.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that as well, and it still happened with about the same frequency.

Comment: are you serving your site from apache? I think that does some sort of caching, that could also result in this.

Comment: no, it's an IIS Express instance started by Visual Studio. But you gave a good idea to check the requests at the IIS level. However I think I'll just live with it for now as I have limited time for debugging this.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://marvelley.com/2011/04/07/preventing-aggressive-caching-of-javascript-files-with-iis7/ - a bit outdated, and not the one bundled with VS, but it might give you a clue on where to look.

Comment: sometimes I get this issue because I don't leave an empty line at the bottom of my `.ts` file.